# How do I create a Search using a Model and a Controller in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

So I am creating a medical app for a school project. I am fairly new to Laravel and even though I've learnt some things so far in it, I am stuck with creating a Search engine for users to search by disease name and symptom. I used Voyager for my admin panel and Jetstream for scaffolding. Livewire is also present. I have a database table called Diagnoses with columns such as name, description, types, symptoms, causes, treatments, advice. After a user logs in and reaches the dashboard (dashboard.blade.php) I want there to be a Search form where they can search for by name and symptom then display the results like a typical search should do.

[Table that I want the results from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Y1u.png)

Table name = Diagnoses, Model = Diagnose, Controller = DiagnoseController.php

How can I accomplish this? Here are the codes that I think I should be working with:

```
web.php:

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('main');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
Voyager::routes();
});

Route::get("/about", function () {
return view('about');
});

Route::get("/contact", function () {
return view('contact');
});
```

Model
Diagnose.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Diagnose extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Controller
DiagnoseController.php:

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DiagnoseController extends Controller
{
   //
}
```

Views
dashboard.blade.php:

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">

        *Put code here*
        

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Yes, I am a novice so that's why I am seeking help. Also if there is a better way or easier way then please show me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with DataTable plugin?

Comment: No. Give me an example.

Comment: https://datatables.net/ see here, using is easy and it has in-build search along with pagination and many more. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't get the time to learn enough in Laravel as I had to be trying to learn it same time while doing the project to meet the milestones that I had to submit. One milestone has already been passed that I didn't submit and another due today which is going to pass again. The final project submission will be due next which is also this month. I am over my head on this one. I uploaded the project to Github with the hopes of getting help but so far no help. The repo is private so if you are offering help then let me know your Username and I will send an invite.

Comment: I think I should just make it public. I am new to Github but here is the link https://github.com/Andre861/my_project

Comment: add me to your gitgub repo, my username: psycho3069

Comment: already modified your project for datatable, if I have access then I can push it as a new branch or maybe on the same branch

Comment: Okay I added you.

Comment: I added a separate branch named `farhan`

Comment: Okay I will check it out now

Comment: Thanks bro. I had to change the table name in your code to 'diagnoses' instead of 'diagnosis' to get it to work. I had a feeling that it would confuse others as it did me before as well lol. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Next, I have to find a way to implement AI or a chat bot which I once did on a PHP project but it didn't work anyway. I don't even remember where I got it from.

Comment: As you are using laravel, you should try using packages. For chatbot you may try this https://github.com/botman/botman

Comment: Okay thanks I will check it out.

Comment: I forgot to ask what I can do to be able to see all the information in the table. The cells don't resize to reveal the information.

Comment: There is a bootstrap class `table-responsive` but somehow it's not working. You may try to apply horizontal scrolling on the table manually.

Comment: I kind of sort it out by changing "white-space: nowrap;" to "white-space: pre-wrap;"

Comment: Great, keep it up!